# Feather found on chicken coop

Tags: birds, bird-identification

I live in the southern part of Zealand, in Denmark. I assembled a chicken coop yesterday, and found this feather on top of the egg-collection box lid this morning. I have been unable to find out which bird this feather is off of using google. any hints are much appreciated.

Timeframe is between 22:00 and 09:00. I am thinking that it is not a pheasant, but a raptor. as to which raptor, I am on rock bottom...

[image: Feather]

Comment: Welcome to outdoors.se! I don't have an answer for you, but if you don't have any luck here I'd suggest you try https://www.birdforum.net/ : lots of very knowledgeable people, and there's a forum specifically for bird identification help (including identification by feather).

Comment: Sure does look like a pheasant to me.

Comment: I have found out that it is indeed a pheasant feather.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took a while to find, partly because I was sure this would turn out to be an owl.  Also, it seems like you already had your own answer before this.  However, to complete the loop here, I do see a match between your photo and the third or fourth feather shown here: https://www.fws.gov/lab/featheratlas/feather.php?Bird=RGPH_tail_female , from which I conclude you have a female ring-necked pheasant.

[image: photo of a series of pheasant feathers]
Photo credit: U.S. Fish and Wildlife Service